# How to reset password if the registration is on phone number from Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Hi all I have my flutter app under development I am using phone number with otp access for signup along with email and username but now I am confused how can I reset the password. With email and password auth it is super easy but with phone number its confusing. I tried searching over internet but didnt found anything I hope anyone from here could have done implemented this in their apps. If so then let me know how I can reset my password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user signs in with phone authentication, there is no password to reset. The system sends them an OTP, and if that expires you can send another one. If you want them to re-sign in with their phone number, you can send them a new OTP with the same API as with which you sent the OTP the first time: [`verifyPhoneNumber`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone#native-verifyphonenumber).

If the user signed in with email+password (too), you can send a password reset email through [`sendPasswordResetEmail`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/sendPasswordResetEmail.html).